# Hilos en snake de 2 jugadores en python 3

Tags: python, hilos

Estoy haciendo el juego snake pero de 2 jugadores pero este se necesitan usar hilos para cada jugador. Al momento de intentar ejecutar, se abre la ventana pero esta se cierra. Y manda el error:

> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
> self.run()
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "c:/Users/axelp/Downloads/snake_v5.py", line 39, in snake
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> cabeza = turtle.Turtle()
> Se esta utilizando la librería turtle y anteriormente tenía la sintaxis así:

```
snake1 = Thread(target = snake("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right", 300, "blue", 0))
    snake2 = Thread(target = snake("w", "s", "a", "d", -300, "yellow", 1))  
    snake1.start()
    snake2.start()
```

Pero se ejecutaba desde el primer momento y no dejaba ejecutar al siguiente hilo por eso cambie la manera de crear el hilo.

```
import turtle
import time
import random
from threading import Thread

posponer = 0.1

#Marcador
puntuacion = [0, 0]
puntuacion_max = 0

# configuracion de la ventana
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Battle Royale Super Ultra Mega Alfa Sniper V3")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 1250, height = 650)
wn.tracer(0)

#Comida
Comida = turtle.Turtle()
Comida.speed(0)
Comida.shape("circle")
Comida.color("red")
Comida.penup()
Comida.goto(0,100)

# texto
texto = turtle.Turtle()
texto.speed(0)
texto.color("white")
texto.penup()
texto.hideturtle()
texto.goto(0,260)
texto.write(f"Score Player One: {puntuacion[0]}, Score Player Two: {puntuacion[1]}    High Score: 0", align = "center", font = ("Sans", 12, "normal"))

def snake(subir, bajar, girar_izquierda, girar_derecha, inicio, color, jugador):
    global puntuacion_max, wn, Comida, texto
    #Cabeza serpiente
    cabeza = turtle.Turtle()
    cabeza.speed(0)
    # turtle, square, triangle, circle, triangle, classic
    cabeza.shape("circle")
    cabeza.color(color)
    cabeza.penup()
    #posicion inicial del jugador
    cabeza.goto(300,0)
    cabeza.direction = "stop"
    #segmentos / cuerpo de la serpiente
    segmentos = []
    #Funciones
def arriba():
    cabeza.direction = "up"

def abajo():
    cabeza.direction = "down"

def izquierda():
    cabeza.direction = "left"

def derecha():
    cabeza.direction = "right"

def pausa():
    cabeza.direction = "stop"

def mov():
    if cabeza.direction == "up":
        y = cabeza.ycor()
        cabeza.sety(y + 20)

    if cabeza.direction == "down":
        y = cabeza.ycor()
        cabeza.sety(y - 20)

    if cabeza.direction == "left":
        x = cabeza.xcor()
        cabeza.setx(x - 20)

    if cabeza.direction == "right":
        x = cabeza.xcor()
        cabeza.setx(x + 20)
        
#Teclado
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(arriba, subir)
wn.onkeypress(abajo, bajar)
wn.onkeypress(izquierda, girar_izquierda)
wn.onkeypress(derecha, girar_derecha)
wn.onkeypress(pausa, "p")

while True:
    wn.update()

    #Coliciones con los bordes
    if cabeza.xcor() > 600 or cabeza.xcor() < -600 or cabeza.ycor() > 300 or cabeza.ycor() < -300:
        time.sleep(1)
        cabeza.goto(inicio,0)
        Comida.goto(0, 100)
        cabeza.direction = "stop"

        # Borrar los segmentos.
        for segmento in segmentos:
            segmento.hideturtle()
        if len(segmentos) != 0:
            segmentos.remove(nuevo_segmento)

        #Limpiar lista de segmentos
        segmentos.clear()

        #Resetear marcador
        puntuacion[jugador] = 0
        texto.clear()
        texto.write("Score Player One: {}, Score Player Two: {}    High Score: {}".format(puntuacion[0], puntuacion[1], puntuacion_max),
                align = "center", font = ("Sans", 12, "normal"))

    # colision de comida
    if cabeza.distance(Comida) < 20:
        x = random.randint(-580, 580)
        y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        Comida.goto(x,y) 

        nuevo_segmento = turtle.Turtle()
        nuevo_segmento.speed(0)
        nuevo_segmento.shape("circle")
        nuevo_segmento.color(color)
        nuevo_segmento.penup()
        segmentos.append(nuevo_segmento)

        #Aumentar marcador
        puntuacion[jugador] += 10

        if puntuacion[jugador] > puntuacion_max:
            puntuacion_max = puntuacion[jugador]

        texto.clear()       
        texto.write("Score Player One: {}, Score Player Two: {}    High Score: {}".format(puntuacion[0], puntuacion[1], puntuacion_max),
                align = "center", font = ("Sans", 12, "normal"))

    #Mover el cuerpo de la serpiente
    totalseg = len (segmentos)
    for index in range(totalseg -1, 0, -1):
        x = segmentos[index -1].xcor()
        y = segmentos[index -1].ycor()
        segmentos[index].goto(x, y)

    if totalseg > 0:
        x = cabeza.xcor()
        y = cabeza.ycor()
        segmentos[0].goto(x,y)

    mov()

    #Colisiones con el cuerpo 
    for segmento in segmentos:
        if segmento.distance(cabeza)< 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            cabeza.goto(inicio,0)
            Comida.goto(0, 100)
            cabeza.direction = "stop"

            #Esconder los segmentos
            for segmento in segmentos:
                segmento.goto(1300,1300)

            segmentos.clear()

    time.sleep(posponer)

def Main(): 
    '''
    snake1 = Thread(target = snake("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right", 300, "blue", 0))
    snake2 = Thread(target = snake("w", "s", "a", "d", -300, "yellow", 1))  
    snake1.start()
    snake2.start()
    
    '''  
    snake1 = Thread(name = 'snake', target=snake, args=("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right", 300, "blue", 0))
    snake2 = Thread(name = 'snake2', target=snake, args=("w", "s", "a", "d", -300, "yellow", 1))
    snake1.start()
    snake2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Es muy curioso que hayan aparecido en las últimas semanas varias preguntas que intentan usar el módulo turtle para implementar un videojuego (véase [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417361/como-puedo-ejecutar-2-funciones-al-mismo-tiempo-dentro-de-un-bucle-while-true)). No sé si será que eres la misma persona que ha abierto otra cuenta, o sois dos personas diferentes. En el segundo caso la casualidad es bien curiosa. En cualquier caso, te digo lo que dije a él. Turtle **no está pensado para hacer juegos**. Mira otras librerías como pygame o pyxel.

Answer (score 0):

Al ejecutar tu código aparece el siguiente error: `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`

**Para que dos jugadores utilicen la misma interfaz tendrías que cambiar completamente tu código**, pero si lo que quieres es mostrar dos ventanas iguales podrías utilizar `subprocess`. Por ejemplo:

```py
# import sys, subprocess
# ...

def Main(): 
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
            subprocess.Popen(f'{sys.executable} {sys.argv[0]}')
    else:
        snake("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right", 300, "blue", 0) # Puedes pasar argumentos por línea de comandos o hacer que sean aleatorios con random
```

En este ejemplo, si ejecutas `python snake_v5.py` se abrirá una instancia del juego, si ejecutas `python snake_v5.py 2` se abrirán dos instancias. Pero **dos usuarios no podrán jugar a la vez porque solamente una de las instancias tendrá el foco en un momento dado.**

Realmente tienes que adaptar el código para que el juego permita dos jugadores (en la misma interfaz), y que cada uno utilice distintas teclas para jugar. Puedes hacerlo sin *threads* y sin *subprocesos*.

Un saludo!